# Mathematical Induction proof $\sum_{k=0}^n 11^k$

Tags: induction

I have a question about methematical induction. I have to proof that:

$\require{cancel}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n 11^k$$

Knowing that:  $$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{1 - a^{k+1}}{1-a} $$

I have the base:

$$ 11^0  = \frac{1-11^{0+1}}{1-11}$$
$$ 1 = \frac{-10}{-10} $$
$$ 1 = 1 $$

Hypothesis:
$$ 1 + 11 + 121 + ... + 11^k = \frac{1-11^{k+1}}{1-11}$$

Conclusion:
$$1 + 11 + 121 + ... + 11^k + 11^{k+1}= \frac{1-11^{k+2}}{1-11}$$
$$\frac{1-11^{k+1}}{1-11} + 11^{k+1}= \frac{1-11^{k+2}}{1-11}$$
$$\frac{1-11^{k+1}}{-10} + 11^{k+1}= \frac{1-11^{k+2}}{-10}$$

$$\frac{1-11^{k+1} + 10.11^{k+1}}{\cancel{-10}} = \frac{1-11^{k+2}}{\cancel{-10}}$$

Then: 
$$1-11^{k+1} + 10.11^{k+1} = 1-11^{k+2}$$

From here I don't know how to continue. I think I'm missing some properties.
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: I think you forgot to add what it should equal to.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prove by induction

$\sum_\limits {k=0}^n 11^k = \frac{1-11^{k+1}}{1-11}$

You have already take care of the base case.

Inductive hypothesis:

suppose,
$\sum_\limits {k=0}^n 11^k = \frac{1-11^{n+1}}{1-11}$

show that,
$\sum_\limits {k=0}^{n+1} 11^k = \frac{1-11^{n+2}}{1-11}$

$\sum_\limits {k=0}^{n+1} 11^k\\
\sum_\limits {k=0}^{n} 11^k + 11^{n+1}$

$\frac{1-11^{n+1}}{1-11} + 11^{n+1}$
,by the inductive hypothesis

$\frac{1-11^{n+1}+(1-11)11^{n+1}}{1-11}\\
\frac{1-11^{n+1}+11^{n+1}-11^{n+2}}{1-11}\\
\frac{1-11^{n+2}}{1-11}$

QED

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the inductive hypothesis for $k$ you have $$1+11+11^2+\dots+11^{k+1}=(1+11+11^2+\dots+11^k)+11^{k+1}=\left(\frac{1-11^{k+1}}{1-11}\right)+11^{k+1}$$ you should then continue $$=\frac{1-11^{k+1}+11^{k+1}(1-11)}{1-11}$$ $$=\frac{1-11^{k+2}}{1-11}$$ which is the required result for $k+1$, thus completing the induction.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, 
$$ \forall |x| > 0, \sum_{k=0}^{n} a^k = \frac{a^{n+1} - 1}{a-1}$$. 
Also, I think you forgot to mention what the summation should equal to.